# Get values from grid

Tags: extjs

I added an actioncolumn to my grid, and i am trying to get a grid value when it is pushed.

this is my actioncolumn:

```
xtype: 'actioncolumn',
width: 30,
sortable: false,
menuDisabled: true,
items: [{
    icon: 'images/refresh16x16.png',
    scope: this,
    handler: this.onBidHistoryGridlClick
}
```

This is my listener:

```
onBidHistoryGridlClick: function(record, grid, rowIndex){
    alert(grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).column_name);
}
```

This doesnt work.

[image: pic]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the record in the listener arguments, use it!

```
record.get('column_name')
```

You were probably close with your own tentative, but you forgot that what you get from the store is a record, not a raw data object. So this would rather have been:

```
grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).get('column_name')
```

**Update**

You've got your handler's arguments wrong (check the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-cfg-handler)). This should be:

```
onBidHistoryGridlClick: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record){
    alert(record.get('column_name'));
}
```

Comment: I tryed using record, but i get an error : "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get'" . Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @rixo's answer, you may need to use the "data" attribute depending on the context (event handler callback function):

```
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).data;
                    alert(rec.toSource());  // this only works in Mozilla Firefox
                    var rec_col_val = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).data.col_name;
                    alert(rec_col_val);
```